# What is unit of Text font size unit in Swift

Tags: swift, fonts

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .padding()             
            .font(.system(size: 12))
    } 
}
```

Is this 12pt?

I am not sure if font that I am seeing is 12pt.

Comment: yes it is poitns

Comment: Are you running under Mac Catalyst, perhaps? If you haven’t changed to the Mac Idiom, all metrics gets scaled slightly.